# Advanced Drive API Service returns "Shared drive not found: [file id]" on Drive.Permissions.remove

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a project where I list permissions of all files in a GSuite domain Drive of a user (not a Team Drive) that are shared externally with users outside the organization - I do this using Drive API v3 with an access token for the particular user. The domain admin then goes in and runs a script to remove permissions for the external users - this is done from the Advanced Drive Service with domain admin permissions. I am having an issue removing access to those files for some combinations of external users and files, having an error related to a shared drive not being found, when in fact I am trying to remove permissions for a file that is not located in a shared drive but in the user's Drive. It works in 99.8% of the cases, but fails in the remaining 0.2% which is very strange. There is nothing particular about the files/permissions where this fails as far as I can see.

I have tried to no avail removing permissions using Drive API v2 and v3 with endpoint:

[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/[v2|v3]/files/[fileId]/permissions/[permissionId]](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/%5Bv2%7Cv3%5D/files/%5BfileId%5D/permissions/%5BpermissionId%5D)

The code I am currently using to remove permissions for a particular file and user is:

```
Drive.Permissions.remove(fileId, permissionId,{useDomainAdminAccess: true});
```

**Expected result**: permission successfully removed.

**Actual result** ([fileId] is the actual file id, not shown for privacy):

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.delete failed with error: Shared drive not found: [fileId]

---

**UPDATE**

Sure, happy to add more details:

```
//CODE THAT GETS THE LIST OF PERMISSIONS FROM GOOGLE DRIVE FOR USERS EXTERNAL FROM THE ORGANIZATION THAT HAVE ACCESS TO FILES FROM USERS IN THE ORGANIZATION
function processDriveFilesForUser(userEmail, oldPageToken, readFiles, accessToken, userDomain) {

  if (!accessToken) {
    return null;
  }

  var params = {
    pageSize: 1000,
    spaces: 'drive',
    q: '"me" in owners and trashed = false'.replace('me', userEmail),
    fields: 'files(id, name, permissions(id,emailAddress)),nextPageToken',
    orderBy: 'modifiedTime desc'
  };
  var data = [];
  var pageToken = oldPageToken;

  do {
    if (pageToken) {
      params.pageToken = pageToken;
    }

    var response = makeHttpGetRequest"('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', params, accessToken);

    if (response && response.error) {
      return '';
    }

    var files = response && response.files ? response.files : [];

    for (var f = 0; f < files.length; f += 1) {
      try {
        var permissions = files[f].permissions || [];

        for (var p = 0; p < permissions.length; p += 1) {
          var permission = permissions[p];

          if (permission.emailAddress && permission.emailAddress !== userEmail && permission.emailAddress.indexOf(userDomain) === -1) {

            data.push([userEmail, files[f].id, files[f].name, permission.emailAddress.toLowerCase(), "x".concat(permission.id)]);

          }
        }
      } catch (err) {// do nothing
      }
    }

    pageToken = response && response.nextPageToken ? response.nextPageToken : '';
  } while (pageToken )());


  return pageToken;
}

function makeHttpGetRequest(apiUrl, params, accessToken, isAdmin) {
  var url = makeQueryString(apiUrl, params);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(accessToken)
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });
  if(response.getResponseCode() != 200){
    console.log("Response code: " + response.getResponseCode() + ", response: " + response.getContentText() + ", url: " + apiUrl + " params " + JSON.stringify(params) + " is admin? " + isAdmin);
  }
  return JSON.parse(response);
};

//CODE THATE REMOVES PERMISSIONS FOR USERS IN THE BLOCK LIST (AMONG EXTERNAL USERS)
function blockUsersInGoogleDrive(ss,sheetName){

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var count = data.length;
var row = 0;
var hasErrors = false;
var blocks = getBlockList();
console.log("block list " + JSON.stringify(blocks));


for (row = 0; row < count ; row += 1) {
  var _data$row = _slicedToArray(data[row], 5),
      userEmail = _data$row[0],
      fileId = _data$row[1],
      fileName = _data$row[2],
      sharedEmail = _data$row[3],
      _data$row$ = _data$row[4],
      permissionId = _data$row$ === void 0 ? '' : _data$row$;
  
  if (userEmail && sharedEmail && fileId && permissionId) {
    if (blocks.indexOf(sharedEmail) !== -1 || blocks.indexOf(getDomainFromEmail(sharedEmail)) !== -1) {
        Utilities.sleep(200);
        var pid = permissionId.replace("x","");
        Drive.Permissions.remove(fileId, pid,{useDomainAdminAccess: true});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks again!!

Comment: Please show your full code to better understand the issue, it could be a problem with how you're iterating through the file ID. Additionally, if you know which files the code is failing for, please try to remove the permissions manually as well, if it fails when doing it manually (through the UI), then there might be a bug

Comment: Thanks @AMolina , I updated the question to include details on how we iterate through file ids. The user whose account is being used to run the script via trigger did try this on the UI [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete) and it worked successfully so it does seem to have the correct permissions, it's just the way we are using them through the API that doesn't work.

Comment: You mentioned that the target Drive is not a shared one. In the `useDomainAdminAccess` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/delete#parameters) it's stated that if the parameter is set to `true` it will seek for a shared Drive with the permission ID